# dynamically created form with events in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am new to jquery and i realize that i might be asking a banal question, but i cant seem to find a solution:
i want to create a form where after the user selected the option 'yes' in a Drop-down menu, more fields will appear, along with an additional Drop-down menu, with the same question. the idea is to keep adding more fields, as long as the user selects 'yes' 
i realize it should involve on() or change().

the basic should look something like this:

```
<div id="moreFields">
 <fieldset class="input-block"><label for="otherProvider">other Providers?</label>
  <div class="dropdown">
   <select id="otherProvider" name="otherProvider" class="dropdown-select">
    <option value="no">no</option>
    <option value="yes">yes</option>
  </select></div></fieldset>
</div>
$('document').ready( function()
 {
   $('#otherProvider').change(function()
      {
        //add more fields, and add a new dropdown menu.
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you lookin for?

```
$(document).ready( function()
 {
   $('#moreFields').on('change','#otherProvider',function()
      {
          if($(this).val() == 'yes'){
             $('#moreFields').append('<fieldset class="input-block"><label for="otherProvider">other Providers?</label><div class="dropdown"><select id="otherProvider" name="otherProvider" class="dropdown-select"><option value="no">no</option><option value="yes">yes</option></select></div></fieldset>');
          }
      }
   );
 });
```

[**DEMO Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/j6uqrxyw/)

Edit: As A.Wolff noticed and he is right .. IDs must be unique so use Classes instead ..

Comment: there is no element in DOM of type `document` ;) And because IDs must be unique on document context, and don't see the point of delegating event here. EDIT: i see you are duplicating ID, so rendering invalid HTML markup

Comment: @A.Wolff updated :) .. I know you are a v.good programmer and feeling happy to see you here :) .. reading your edit :)

Answer (score 0):

Done without jQuery:

```
<div id="moreFields">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="otherProvider">other Providers?</label> <select class="dropdown-select" id="otherProvider" name="otherProvider" onchange="myFunct(this.id)">
      <option value="no">
        no
      </option>

      <option value="yes">
        yes
      </option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
</div>

<script>
function myFunct(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  var valu = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  if (valu == "yes") {
    var div = document.createElement("fieldset");
    div.innerHTML = "other Providers?";
    var select = document.createElement("select");
    select.innerHTML = '<option value="no">no</option><option value="yes">yes</option>';
    select.id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
    select.onchange = function() {
      myFunct(this.id);
    };
    div.appendChild(select);
    document.getElementById("moreFields").appendChild(div);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why generating random ID? Why not instead using class? BTW, the new generated elements have no event bound. Maybe not what expect OP (but could be)

Comment: They have a event, onchange

Comment: Sorry, i didn't seen it, my bad :(